# android remote database

Tags: android, database, web-services

I'm novice in android. I'm writing an android application which requires the data like comments and scores to sync with the central database. I'm planning creating a simple web service and sync the data with the app.

Please suggest me some of the best methods and technologies which i should use. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a central database on a remote server.

Develop a RESTful web service to access the data.

Store the data on your local device in a SQLite database.

Communicate between both sides with good old http.

Hard to be more precise with such a vague question.